# How to show a progress bar while reading a xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Im using Crytal report WPF Application to generate a report with xml file and this is the code i use

```
    protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet dset = new DataSet1();
        DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
        reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/data.xml");
        dset.Tables[0].Merge(reportData.Tables[0]);
        ReportDocument report = null;
        report = new CrystalReport1();
        report.SetDataSource(dset.Tables[0]);
        reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;

    }
```

so someone can provide me a idea or example how to show a progress bar window while xml file read?

just want to show busy indicator to let users know that application is reading xml file and generating report

```
reportData.ReadXml("http://192.168.1.10/test/data.xml");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read XML not in UI thread. For your purpose you can use [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

Comment: Good advice, but he'll also need a `ReadXml` method that allows progress reporting (for instance an event that is fired when the read process goes from 10 to 20 percents).

Comment: @ken2k, Maybe he means indeterminate progressbar?

Comment: Yes, maybe he means some kind of 'busy indicator', you're right. Should be clarified by the OP.

Comment: yes just want to show busy indicator to let users know that application is reading xml file and generating report

Comment: @GihanLasita, So use `BackgroundWorker` as I mentioned.